# Slug urls with Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, slug

How would you get `post/my-title` (with a custom slug) instead of `posts/2` (with id) in Ember.js?

My approach was to add and use a slug in my model but it doesn't work on direct access. Using a `{{link-to}}` helper it works, also the slug. I assume the error lies in the `PageRoute`'s model. Tried `return this.store.find('page', {'slug': params.page_slug})` without any luck.

Example code: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AVAgUZAb/5/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mismatching versions of Ember Data.  In the `PageRoute` you are using the model definition to try and find the record which is no longer correct. See https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

Additionally you really should just replace `id` with the slug since you've essentially rendered the idea of unique items worthless (aka `slug` doesn't have to be unique, but `id` does, so what happens when you have multiple items with the same slug?)  If your slugs will always be unique, you might as well use them as the `id` there is no constraint that id must be numeric.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/AVAgUZAb/9/edit

Comment: But how would you ensure that the the slug always stays unique?