# Ember.js: Custom Slug URLs not working after refresh

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to setup custom slug URLs for my page models in Ember. They're working so far when I call the links from the index page. What's not working however, is that **if I refresh the page with one of my custom URLs, the model is not found anymore** and I'm being redirected to my "not found" page. So maybe it's a "timing" problem and I should load the models in a different way?

I followed the [tutorial in the Ember guides](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) and checked [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21516440/slug-urls-with-ember-js) but I still cannot get it to work.

Here's my source code snippet so far: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hidefetido/1/

Thank you very much in advance - every help/comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to make your model function to handle slug and serialize function to tranform model into url:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.findAsId('company', 'slug', params.company_slug);
  },
  serialize: function (model) {
    return {company_slug: model.get('slug')};
  }
});
```

The second part is optional. There is generally problem with server:
If you call for `/entity/slug` ember-data will think that slug is id. So you have to use `this.store.find('company', {slug:slug});` but this will return array so you have to transform it. This can be simplified by implementing own function into store.

```
findAsId: function (type, field, value) {
    Ember.assert("You need to pass a type, field and value.", arguments.length === 3);

    var entity = this.all(type).findBy(field, value);
    if (Ember.isEmpty(entity)) {
        var query = {};
        query[field] = value;
        return this.find(type, query).then(function (array) {
            Ember.assert('Must find only one object. Found:' + array.get('length'), array.get('length') === 1);
            return array.get('firstObject');
        });
    } else {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve){
        resolve(entity);
    });
  }
}
```

Example of store.js is on [gist](https://gist.github.com/Keeo/0d8d99a50edfdd120bf0).

Comment: It works like that, thanks a lot! Still weird that it has to be such a complicated solution and there's no clear documentation about it ...

Comment: I have to agree. Btw I was not able to pinpoint why your code does not work yesterday. But now I have an idea. You are using ```return this.modelFor('pages').findBy('slug', params.page_slug);``` to get page. But this requires ```PagesRoute``` to be loaded. But based on your rotes I don't believe it will be on page reload.